# Create Dropdownlist Real Date (birthday)

Tags: validation, date

I need to create a set of `DropdownList` objects filled with valid dates (for birthdays).

Example:

```
31/02/2013 -> not possible, invalid
31/12/2013 -> possible, valid
```

How do I create 3 `DropdownList` objects, one each for Day, Month, and Year, and validate the resulting date?

Comment: What language? What environment? What have you tried?

Comment: I use: ASP.net 4.0, C#. (build for website). Please, help me, thank so much PRO !